# Image of tangent circles within the area between two circles.

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Consider two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$. $C_2$ lies within $C_1$. Let $S_1...S_n$ be circles lies between $C_1$ and $C_2$, and the following were satisfied:

(i):Each circle $S_i$ is tangent to C1 and C2

(ii):Each $S_i$ is tangent to $S_{i+1}$, $S_n$ is tangent to $S_1$.

The problem is to prove that the number n is independent of the choice of the circles {$S_i$}.

Attempt:

WIthout losing generality, we can assume that the big circle $C_1$ passes through the origin and orthogonal to real axis, then under conformal map 1\z, it becomes a vertical line. The small circle $C_2$ is mapped to another circle lie on one side of the vertical line. The small circles $S_i$ should be tangent to both the line and the image of $C_2$. But I don't know how to prov that the number of small circles are finite and independent of choice. Any help or hint is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that $C_1$ has its centre on the real axis?

Comment: It's a valid assumption, isn't it?

Comment: Yup, of course, because translation is a conformal mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an inversia such that two given circles will be with common center.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what do you mean?

Comment: @KIYORI If for given two circles there is a common center then your statement is obvious. About inversia see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry

Comment: Do you mean that if C1 and C2 are not co-centered, we can take inversion to make them co-centered?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @KIYORI Y Yes of course. I am ready to explain how we can find the circle of the inversia.

Comment: Please do explain, it's a little bit hard to figure it out purely by wiki.

Comment: Let $O_1$ and $O_2$ be centers of the circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively. Let $C$ be a point on the line $O_1O_2$ such that if $CA$ and $CB$ are tangent segments to $C_1$ and $C_2$ then $AC=BC$. Now take the circle of the radius $AC$ with a center in the point $C$. Let this circle intersects the line $O_1O_2$ in points $M$ and $N$. Now, prove that the inversia with center in the point  $M$ transfers $C_1$ and $C_2$ to co-centered circles.